# Using various fonts in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I need to use some fonts with angularjs and store the same in db

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Address</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <textarea class="form-control" type="text"
        ng-model="Address" cols="40" rows="5"
        ng-style="{'font-family':Monotype Corsiva}"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to save this detail with the font "Monotype Corsiva" in db. Can anyone help me out

Comment: You can do it in this way, you should create a field in your DB table for the font. then send the font to your DB as you want table columns example `id, content, font`

Comment: I have the font field in db. But when I use "Monotype Corsiva" also. It gets saved in a normal font

Answer (score 0):

You should get the fontFamily and the address to your controller then you can send them to your database

This is a simple example for it:

*Remember: You should send them to your database in a correct way.*

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.formData = {
      address: "",
      fontFamily: 'Monotype Corsiva'
    }
    // Use this function to send font to your database
    $scope.send = function () {
      var address = $scope.formData.address;
      var fontFamily = $scope.formData.fontFamily;
      
      // this line for test, remove it when every thing be clear for you
      alert('address: ' + $scope.formData.address  + "\n" + 'fontFamily: ' + $scope.formData.fontFamily);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Address</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <textarea class="form-control" type="text"
        ng-model="formData.address" cols="40" rows="5"
        ng-style="{'font-family': formData.fontFamily}"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="send()" >Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If if do like this , Then when i access it by expression say {{formData.address}} somewhere. I should get the expression in Monotype Corsiva right? and also when i alert it, it is not in monotype corsiva

Comment: I did as you told. But when i access it outside the text area with the expression {{formData.address}} it is not in monotype corsiva.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548857/how-to-use-tamil-font-while-forming-a-pdf

Comment: Can you put the code that you use for accessing the text! www.jsfiddle.net